# Python 3--finding evens/odds in a range

Tags: python-3.x, range

I am new to coding so please forgive me. I am working on a problem to ID the evens & odds in a range. I can do evens & odds and I can do range, my problem is how do I combine them?
This is what I have:

```
    x = range(1, 101)
    if x % 2 == 0
    print("even")
    else:
    print(x)
```

I know it is wrong, I just can't figure out how. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. what do you mean by "combine"?

Comment: `x` is a range, not a number in that range. Did you mean to loop perhaps? `for i in x:` then test `i`?

Comment: yes i think that is what i meant...again so new at this and trying to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you print out even and odd numbers from 1 to 100: I put comment in there for explanation

```
for x in range (1, 101):  #x goes from 1 to 100 and increment by 1 each loop
   if (x % 2 == 0): #if x divide by 2 and the remainder is 0 then it is even
     print(str(x) + " is even") #print x is even. 
   else:
     print(str(x) + " is odd") #if is not even then it is odd so print it out
```

**Break down the code line by line**

- `for x in range (1, 101):` this means x goes from 1 to 100 and each loop the value of x increments by 1. [`For loop`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) is an important programming concept for all languages. Learn it well. The basic `for loop` looks like this in Python: `for i in range(start, end, step)` i goes from start to end and remember end is *not inclusive*. like in our case end is 101 but the iteration stops at loop 100. `step` by default is 1. You may set it to some other value if you desire.
- base on your code I think you understand the `if` and `else` statement so I will skip that here. if you don't leave a comment and I will update with an explanation.
- `print` statement: I think you understand `print()` but you might wonder what is `str(x)` inside the `print` statement. `str()` convert x from a `int` to a `str` so it can be concatenate with `" is even"` and `" is odd"`. you cannot concatenate `str` with `int` in Python. You will get an error

  > TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Welcome to StackOverflow Codenewbie. I hope this helps you understand Python better.

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much for explaining it! Love your explanations, I hope you teach coding! I will try your tips.

Comment: @Codenewbie you are so welcome. If this answer or any other answer solves you problem then please make it as the solution. That way if fellow programmers  sun into the same problem as you in the future they can find the answer easier.

Comment: "mark it as" and "run into" sorry for the typo. My phone's autocorrect is horrendous

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
c = ['even', 'odd']
for x in range(0,100): print (str(x) + ' is ' + c[x%2])
```

Learn every bit of this code. It will help you understand many things.